# Is it possible to create "parameter decorators" (like TypeScript) in Python?

Tags: python, decorator

TypeScript has a feature known as [parameter decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators) — literally a decorator that you can apply to a parameter of a function or method:

```
class BugReport {
  // ... 
  print(@required verbose: boolean) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Another example from [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators):

```
class SomeController {
  // ...
  async findOne(@User() user: UserEntity) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Note in the above examples that the decorators are decorating parameters of each method, not the methods themselves.

I don't think that parameter decorators like this exist in Python (at least as of v3.11, nor could I find any open PEPs that cover it); however, I'm curious to know if there is a way to implement something like this in Python?

It doesn't have to have the exact same syntax, of course; just the same effect.

I'm not super familiar with how parameter decorators work under-the-hood, but my best understanding is that they attach metadata to the corresponding function or method at compile time (so they would likely need to work in tandem with a function/method decorator, metaclass, etc.).

Comment: A _function_ decorator that checks or modifies a specific parameter, sure; so one can get the same effect. A parameter decorator _as such_, no.

Comment: Agree with @CharlesDuffy and on top of that, realize that a function decorator is a full-on meta-function, meaning you can customize it anyway you like, rather than having a feature (more rigidly) dictated to you by the programming language. More info in the PEP at: http://peps.python.org/pep-0318

Comment: (So... exactly how "like TypeScript" does it have to be to count? Does `@requireArgs(verbose = bool)` as a decorator _for the print method_ "count" for this question's purpose? If you set the goalposts to deliberately require a language feature then any language without that feature -- or true LISP-macro-style extensibility -- will fail; but if the goal is just similar functionality, yes, that's very doable).

Comment: Fair point.  I'd like to know what's possible, so if the end result is the same and the syntax is reasonably close, I'd call that a win (e.g., I'd agree that `@requireArgs(verbose=bool)` is probably as close as one can get in this context).

Comment: "It doesn't have to have the exact same syntax, of course; just the same effect." - **what is that effect**? Simply showing me code in a different programming language does not explain what you want the code to do. (This also isn't a Typescript question; tags are for indicating *what knowledge answerers need to have*. I shouldn't need to know anything about Typescript in order to answer the question; rather than expecting that of us, explain *directly* what the code needs to do.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn’t have parameter decorators – only function decorators – but it *does* provide runtime access to type annotations, as well as [`typing.Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated).

```py
from typing import Annotated


class BugReport:

    @validate_required
    def print(self, verbose: Annotated[bool, Required]) -> None:
        ...
```

```
import functools
import inspect
import typing


class Required:
    pass

Required = Required()


def validate_required(fn):
    required = {
        name
        for name, t in inspect.get_annotations(fn).items()
        if typing.get_origin(t) is typing.Annotated
        and Required in typing.get_args(t)[1:]
    }
    signature = inspect.signature(fn)

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def validated(*args, **kwargs):
        bound_args = signature.bind(*args, **kwargs)

        for required_arg in required:
            if bound_args.arguments[required_arg] is None:
                raise ValueError(f"required argument is None: {required_arg!r}")

        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return validated
```

To do this particular kind of thing in practice, you might want to [extend Typeguard](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html) instead, although I honestly wouldn’t recommend it; it’s too fragile and slow.

Answer (score 2):

The closest approach I can think of would be to use a function/method decorator that takes the parameter name as one of its parameters.

A trivial example might look like this:

*Note: this is technically not the same as TypeScript parameter decorators because it changes the runtime behaviour of the method rather than just attaching metadata; I will revisit this when I have more time to see if I can come up with a better implementation*

```py
class UserEntity:
    pass

def UserParam(name: str):
    def decorator(fn):
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            # Inject the UserEntity into the function params.
            return fn(*args, **kwargs, **{name: UserEntity()})
        return decorated
    return decorator

class SomeController:
    @UserParam('user')
    def findOne(self, user: UserEntity):
        print(repr(user))


SomeController().findOne()
```

A more realistic example would likely need to work in tandem with another decorator or metaclass, however.